# layoutIfNeeded cannot work in UIView animation block

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

self is a view, layout may to update it's frame, but it cannot work correct at iOS 10.

There is some answer for layout super, but it cannot work for me.

this code is at UIView class.

e.g.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:self.animationDuration
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
    [self mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
                             make.bottom.equalTo(self.attachedView.mas_bottom).offset(0);
                         }];
                             [self layoutIfNeeded];
                         }
```

Comment: in xib try by selecting 'Center' in 'Content Mode' for your subview

Comment: try =>  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: You miss completion part and use  -> [self.view layoutIfNeeded]

Comment: Can you also show the code where you changed the values of the layout?

Comment: fix by replace with  self.superView .......

Answer (score 0):

Your method should like this and its working on ios 10

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:self.animationDuration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

Comment: but these code are not write at UIViewController but at a UIView class.